# How to Programmatically Disable Named Pipes in SQL Server 2005 Native Client?

Tags: sql-server, named-pipes

How to Programmatically Disable Named Pipes in SQL Server 2005 Native Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to disable NP for *every* application on the client? Can't you just force your own app not to use NP, eg. by requesting TCP *explicitly* in the connection string? Add `tcp:` in front of the datasource name: `Data Source=tcp:servername;...`.

**How to use the server name parameter in a connection string to specify the client network library**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313295